# Spark Shell on Kubernetes with Kerberos enabled Cluster

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, hadoop

I have a hard time to get the spark shell (3.3.1) on kubernetes to work with kerberos. It works in cluster mode and client mode for submit. Here is what we did to get it to work:

cluster mode (works fine):

1. create a krb5.conf configmap and config map containeing `hdfs-site.xml` and `core-site.xml`
2. create a key tab file and mount it into pod doing spark-submit
3. use `spark.kubernetes.hadoop.configMapName` and `spark.kubernetes.kerberos.krb5.configMapName` to make spark mount them
4. set `spark.kerberos.keytab` and `spark.kerberos.principal`

client mode (works fine):

1. mount `hdfs-site.xml` and `core-site.xml` into spark conf dir in submitting pod
2. mount `krb5.conf` into `/etc/krb5.conf`
3. use kinit to get kerberos ticket or set `spark.kerberos.keytab` and `spark.kerberos.principal` (both options work)

spark shell (does not work):

1. mount `hdfs-site.xml` and `core-site.xml` into spark conf dir in submitting pod
2. mount `krb5.conf` into `/etc/krb5.conf`
3. use kinit to get kerberos ticket or set `spark.kerberos.keytab` and `spark.kerberos.principal` (no options works)

What did we try:

1. use kinit and set `spark.kerberos.renewal.credentials` to `ccache` and set env variable KRB5CCNAME to path to where kinit stores the ticket (no effect)
2. verified that configuration files are loaded in spark history server
3. put krb5.conf into spark conf dir
4. use java env arguments to point to krb5.conf (inside spark conf dir)

Observed behavior: Spark does not seem to do any kerberos magic at all. It seems to ignore the kerberos security settings. Not that all settings from client and cluster mode still apply. Here is the error we get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get Kerberos realm
at org.apache.hadoop.security.HadoopKerberosName.setConfiguration(HadoopKerberosName.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:315)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(UserGroupInformation.java:366)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.<init>(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.instance$lzycompute(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:397)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.instance(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:397)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.get(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:418)
at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:424)
at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:413)
at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm
at javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosPrincipal.<init>(KerberosPrincipal.java:159)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil.getDefaultRealm(KerberosUtil.java:120)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.HadoopKerberosName.setConfiguration(HadoopKerberosName.java:69)
... 9 more
```

UPDATE:
Just for testing, I put the krb5.conf on all the hosts and mounted it into the executors. Then the above problem disappeared.

```
spark-shell \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.hostPath.krb5.mount.path=/opt/krb5 \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.hostPath.krb5.options.path=/etc \
  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/opt/krb5/krb5.conf"
```

This could find the Kerberos config. So we did a kinit and got this error:

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:913)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:888)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1616)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1558)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1455)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:242)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:129)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:333)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:900)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:889)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:878)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1046)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:340)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:336)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:353)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.lambda$openFileWithOptions$0(FileSystem.java:4633)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LambdaUtils.eval(LambdaUtils.java:52)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.openFileWithOptions(FileSystem.java:4631)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$FSDataInputStreamBuilder.build(FileSystem.java:4768)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat.$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1(TextFileFormat.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:209)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:364)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:798)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:752)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:856)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3800(Client.java:414)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1677)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1502)
... 53 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:179)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:392)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:623)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2300(Client.java:414)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:843)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:839)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:839)
... 56 more
```

So then we tried using keytabs:

```
spark-shell \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.hostPath.krb5.mount.path=/opt/krb5 \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.hostPath.krb5.options.path=/etc \
  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/opt/krb5/krb5.conf" \
  --conf spark.kerberos.principal=principal \
  --conf spark.kerberos.keytab=principal.keytab
```

Which failed with the above error. But it became clear that the keytab is missing on the executors. So we put it there with Spark.

```
spark-shell \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.hostPath.krb5.mount.path=/opt/krb5 \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.hostPath.krb5.options.path=/etc \
  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/opt/krb5/krb5.conf" \
  --conf spark.kerberos.principal=principal \
  --conf spark.kerberos.keytab=principal.keytab \
  --files /home/principal/principal.keytab
```

We tried putting the `krb5.conf` similar to the keytab, that did not work.

So that worked now. But it has a few drawbacks.

1. The `krb5.conf` we need in spark shell is not the same we want on the hosts
2. <strike>uploading the keytab like this is not safe, it can be taken from the spark archive and misused</strike>

What we would like to have is that this works similar to spark-submit. We would like to mount the `krb5.conf` from a configmap and use the keytab from a secret, or that a secret is created.

How can this be done? Any advice is more than welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, lots of testing. This is a solution that works in shell, client and cluster mode with kerberos on kubernetes:

```
spark-submit ... \
  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/opt/spark/conf/krb5.conf \
  --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/opt/spark/conf/krb5.conf
```

But this only works if `hdfs-site.xml`, `core-site.xml` and `krb5.conf` are placed in SPARK_CONF_DIR. The contents are automatically shipped to executors and drivers. As this option works for all scenarios, using the kerberos and hadoop configmaps seems not favorable. If you only need cluster mode. I would go with those though.

regards